# Eigendecomposition after multiplying by diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvector

Hello,

If we possess the eigendecomposition of a positive definite matrix: $X = U \Sigma U^T$, is there an efficient way to compute the eigendecomposition of $D X D$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the same $U$ works since diagonal matrices commute with everything...

Comment: Paul, that is only true if the diagonal matrix is scalar.

Comment: :) If only it were that easy.  Unfortunately a general diagonal matrix will change the eigenvalues and eigenvectors... It seems like there should be a way to update the eigendecomposition but I'm stumped.   This is for an implementation of Gaussian belief propagation. First mathoverflow question--thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Now I'm definitely confused... are we not working over a field?  What does positive definite mean over a noncommutative ring?

Comment: @Paul: diagonal matrices don't commute with everything, even on $\mathbb{Z}$: $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\\\1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\\\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\neq\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\\\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\\\1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Objection retracted... somewhere deep down I really did know better...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write $\Sigma$ as $T^2$, for positive definite $T$. Set $Y = U T$.

So the eigenvalues of $X$ are the squares of the [singular values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Singular_values.2C_singular_vectors.2C_and_their_relation_to_the_SVD) of $Y$, and what you want to compute are the singular values of $DY$.

There is no formula which gives the singular values of $DY$ in terms of those of $Y$ and $D$. However, there is a famous set of inequalities relating the three sets of singular values, called the Horn inequalities. See Bhatia's article [Linear Algebra to Quantum Cohomology](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2695237), particularly Section 11, for a gentle introduction.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I came across Horn's stuff. So is this related because if you exponentiate the matrices it is addition of exponents as in the paper?

Comment: No and yes. It is not true that $e^{A} e^{B} = e^{A+B}$ so, if $A+B=C$, it need not be true that the eigenvalues of $e^A e^B$ are the exponentials of the eigenvalues of $e^C$. However, it is true that the set of all possible singular values of $e^A e^B$ is the exponential of the set of all possible eigenvalues for $A+B$. This is a theorem of Klyachko http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1799623 and it is discussed in section 11 of the refernce I give above.

Comment: Excellent, thanks that is very helpful!